# CookieManager.getCookie() returns different values

Tags: java, android, cookies

Below is my code to get some cookies post authentication in an android application.

```
String url = "https://host:port/sso/SSOServlet";
BasicCookieStore cookieJar = new BasicCookieStore();
CookieManager cookieMgr = CookieManager.getInstance();
String host = null;
URL urlObj = Util.getUrl(url);
host = urlObj.getHost();

String cookiesHost = cookieMgr.getCookie(host); // value for cookiesHost is JSESSIONID

String cookiesURL = cookieMgr.getCookie(url); // value for cookiesURL is JSESSIONID and a custom Session id for application.
```

So `cookieMgr.getCookie()` returns different value for certain server if I use `host` instead of `url`. Why is that? For some servers, it returns the same values if I use either `host` or `url`.  Why this might be happening?

This was returning same values for host OR url previously, but this one server I am working with, is returning the values I mentioned in the comments of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to determine the exact issue causing the varied results without knowing what is being returned for each variable.

Please provide the values of `cookiesHost` and `cookiesURL` when you are seeing the difference in the cookies.

As mentioned in the first response to your issue if you use `example.com` (HOST), a session and a cookie is created for `example.com`, then most likely a redirect to the BaseURL `www.example.com` creates a new session.

Answer (score 1):

`getHost()` returns just the domain name. For instance, `google.com` out of `http://google.com/search`. I'm guessing your `getUrl()` method returns the entire URL.

This gives the `CookieManager` instance different inputs, resulting in different outputs.

Comment: getUrl returns a URL object. But  different input, but that's not the case for some of the servers. For most servers if use host, I get all cookies. Suddenly I came across a server which was not returning all cookies for the host, but I changed host to url and not getCookie is returning all cookies.